# PDF updating on OS X Yosemite

Tags: pdf, mac, viewers

Since OS X Yosemite, the standard Preview.app no longer seems to keep position when updating a LaTeX PDF. I tried PDFView, which does keep position, but renders text very ugly. (Same engine as Evince?) Any other options or hacks to make the standard Preview.app, which is otherwise excellent, keep position?

I don't want to use any integrated development environment, but just a basic text editor (joe) in a terminal, because it has the keybindings that are programmed into my spine. Unless, of course, someone can point to an IDE with easily configurable key bindings, supporting multi-key sequences.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Can you tell us how you are calling the pdf viewer.

Comment: Same with Skim as PDFView: ugly rendering reminiscent of Linux.

Comment: Andrew: the open command from the command line. Used to do that in both Lion and Mavericks without trouble. Now in Yosemite Preview.app no longer keeps position. Mind you, it's a completely fresh install of the OS. I also have 'Start on last viewed page' set in the preferences.

Comment: I use Skim which comes with a `displayline` script to start at a particular line.  Rendering is good for me.

Comment: @AndrewSwann are you on Yosemite yet?  This appears to be a bug with Preview (and the other PDF viewers that use the same rendering engine) on Yosemite.  See [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151995/finer-control-of-preview-anti-aliasing-font-smoothing).

Comment: Re: an IDE with configurable key bindings, any Cocoa text editor (TextMate, TextEdit, TeXShop, etc) should support multi-keystroke bindings. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html) shows how to do this. Google reveals a [GUI for keybindings](http://www.cocoabits.com/KeyBindingsEditor/Manual/) but I've never tried it.

Comment: @Thruston Yes, I am on Yosemite.

Comment: How does the PDF behave in Adobe Reader XI?

Comment: IMHO this is only very slightly related to TeX and should be migrated to [apple.sx](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Skim does the job very well on my new Macbook Pro with retina display, but on an older iMac at work it makes my eyes bleed -- even more so than the poor resolution of the display itself. In other news, my question seems to be a dupe of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153147/yosemites-preview-app-goes-to-top-of-document-when-pdf-changes

Comment: It is nonsense to say 'ugly rendering reminiscent of Linux'. GNU/Linux can render fonts beautifully. My laptop, for example, does so using [this](http://bohoomil.com/). [Adobe reader cannot cope with some things but that is Adobe's fault.]

Comment: @cfr Yes, it could, in the age of bitmap fonts. But Freetype has always been fugly if not installing the manual hinter that is usually disabled, and using older manually hinted fonts. Anyway, off topic...

Comment: @Thom The work I linked to does not use bitmap fonts.

Comment: I've used Skim since PDFView died (beginning of 2007) and I am fully satisfied by it: I see no rendering problem. Just a few random crashes when *many* windows are open. It uses exactly the same rendering framework as Preview and has much more TeX related features.

Answer (score 1):

It is not Preview.app, of course, but TeXShop.app (comes with MacTex) can be used as a standalone previewer with the external editor of your choice (e.g. joe). In that case, it can be configured to automatically update, and you can tell TeXShop about your editor by configuring the preferences. When using an external editor, tick 'Automatic Preview Update' in preferences and then open .pdf with TeXShop.

Comment: TeXShop.app does have a feature called "Key Binding". I am not sure if it is what OP wants. But if it is then this post is an answer to the second paragraph of the question. Please give us more explanation like how to setup/import key binding data.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. This answer has been flagged as of low quality, but you can improve it quite easily by expanding on the points others have suggested. Really, it should be a comment rather than answer so I'm not sure if this is the best thing to do, but if you can turn it into an answer, that would be great!